# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource for count row

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

i got an error mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource

here's my code

```
$carikomoditas = $_POST['cari'];
$cariquery=mysqli_query($connect,"
    SELECT * 
    FROM komoditassample
    WHERE id='$carikomoditas'
") or die('Error');

$data = mysqli_fetch_array($cariquery);
$res = mysql_num_rows($data);
echo $res;
```

I tried the mysqli num too but same error

Comment: Mixing `mysqli with mysql`

Comment: `$cariquery=mysqli_query($connect,"select* from `komoditassample` where id='$carikomoditas'") or die(mysqli_error($connect));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$carikomoditas=$_POST['cari'];
$cariquery=mysqli_query($connect,"select*from komoditassample where id='$carikomoditas'") or die('Error');
$res=mysqli_num_rows($cariquery); // result set

$data=mysqli_fetch_array($cariquery);

echo $res;
```

Answer (score 1):

use mysqli and the parameter should be the query

```
$carikomoditas = $_POST['cari'];
$cariquery = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from komoditassample where id='$carikomoditas'") or die('Error');

$data = mysqli_fetch_array($cariquery);
$res  = mysqli_num_rows($cariquery);
echo $res;
```

**Edited: In more detail**

```
$carikomoditas = isset($_POST['cari']) ? $_POST['cari'] : 0;

if (!empty($carikomoditas))
{
    $cariquery  = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from komoditassample where id='$carikomoditas'") or die('Error');

    $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($cariquery);

    if ($total_rows > 0)
    {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($cariquery);
        /*
        Display the retrieved database content here
        */
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'No record found';
    }

}
else
{
echo 'Error: carikomoditas not valid';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the right answer

```
$carikomoditas=$_POST['cari'];
    //echo$carikomoditas;
    $cariquery=mysqli_query($connect,"select*from komoditassample where id='$carikomoditas'") or die('Errorororor');
    $res=mysqli_num_rows($cariquery);
    echo $res;
```

the mysqli_num_row parameter must be the mysqli query variable not the fetch